# Having trouble accessing the values of a dictionary whose keys are timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I created `mini_df` which is a dictionary of dataframes, by slicing the datetime index of another dataframe.

So now I have  `mini_df` whose keys are datetimes, but I'm having trouble with the format of the keys. I'm not exactly sure of the format I have to type to access the values of the key.

When I type

```
mini_dfs.keys()

>>> dict_keys([Timestamp('2010-02-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-02-12 00:00:00'),    Timestamp('2010-03-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-04-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-04-13 00:00:00')........,
```

However, variations of

```
mini_dfs[('2015-07-06 00:00:00')]
mini_dfs["timestamp('2015-07-06 00:00:00')"]
mini_dfs["Timestamp('2015-10-19 00:00:00')"]
mini_dfs["('2015-10-19 00:00:00')"]
mini_dfs['2010-02-11 00:00:00']
mini_dfs[ Timestamp('2010-02-11 00:00:00') ] # name 'Timestamp' is not defined
```

Are all leading to key errors.

What exactly is the correct format of the key?

Comment: I would expect the printed version of the data to match the syntax used to express a literal. Did you try `mini_dfs.Timestamp('2010-02-11 00:00:00')`?

Comment: If I type exactly what you wrote, I'm getting the following error
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'`

Comment: Oh right, that's the object, not the module. Well, follow Victor, he knows more about it than I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not a string, but rather a `Timestamp` object.

```
import pandas
mini_dfs[ pandas.Timestamp('2010-02-11 00:00:00') ]
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`name 'Timestamp' is not defined`

Comment: I've updated the answer to import pandas. Try again and it should work.